# Facebook "like" adding extra parameters in url ex: fb_action_ids fb_action_types

Tags: parameters, facebook-like

Is there anyway to turn this off?   My application server uses strict parameter definitions and frankly all these extra parameters break my pages and the user gets a 404 for clicking a "liked" link.

And they are changing often (the passed extra parameters) so I would like to simply turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened with one of my websites and as i saw on Google - there's still many others. When i started to think about this problem, i discovered that the best solution would be a "301 redirect" to a canonical (original) address of a page or article.

As long as these _GET parameters don't make any conflicts with your website, you can still set a valid path for redirection, and that was my choice. In fact - every website or application could add these parameters, that's why i think - 404 in this case is a bad idea.

Visitors don't like to see these 404 pages anyway.

Comment: That's the problem.  I do not control to show them 404's the application server does it since it's getting parameters that are not previously defined.